# Digital Topology Quotient Space

Tags: general-topology

Show that the digital plane topology can be obtained as a quotient space that results from a partition of $\Bbb R^2$ in the standard topology.

The digital plane has a basis defined as:

- $\{(m,n)\}$ -- $m,n$ are odd
- $\{(m+a,n) \mid a=-1,0,1\}$ -- $m$ even, $n$ is odd
- $\{(m,n+b) \mid b=-1,0,1\}$ -- $m$ odd, $n$ is even
- $\{(m+a,n+b) \mid a,b=-1,0,1\}$ -- $m,n$ are both even

I can see how you would could get the digital circle from a quotient space pretty easily, but I'm not sure specifically about this problem involving the digital plane. Help would really great.

Comment: This is pretty confusing to read. What do you mean it is "defined as" those things? Is it each part independently or is it the union of them?

Comment: When I said defined I meant that that is it's basis. It's also a product of two digital line topologies. Single point of course are closed, and the even numbers would be open..

Comment: So, it's $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ with that as a basis? @James

Comment: ^Yes that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $q:\Bbb R\to\Bbb Z$ to the integers with the digital line topology
$$q(x)=
\begin{cases}
x,  &\text{ if $x$ is even} \\
m,  &\text{ if $x\in(m-1,m+1)$ for some odd } m
\end{cases}$$
is an open surjective map, thus a quotient map. Its square $(q\times q):\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb Z^2$ is thus an open quotient map as well.

Comment: May I ask what motivated someone to downvote my answer?

Comment: This actually helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: why was this marked down?

Comment: @H_B: It was part of a serial downvote on me. [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124930/doubt-about-proof-of-factorization-f-pi-where-i-is-acyclic-cofibration-and) was downvoted only ten seconds earlier. Don't know what caused someone to do this. Unfortunately, it was not reversed automatically by the system as it usually does, maybe because there were only two downvotes in a row. Of course, it could still be a coincidence, who knows?

Comment: I am actually working on this problem, and was hoping you could tell me how we know the square of the quotient map is also a quotient map. There is a section of Munkres that points out that this need not always be true.

Comment: Ok I think I understand why. Its because they are OPEN quotient maps.

Comment: @H_B: That's correct. Product of open maps is open.

Comment: Could you tell me how we define the product of maps?

Comment: @H_B: Well, if $(f_i:X_i\to Y_i)_i$ is a family of maps, then there is a product $f:\prod X_i\to \prod Y_i$, applying $f_i$ to the $i$-th coordinate of the point.