# Representing map as a composition of cofibration and fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

It is a fairly standard result that any map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ can be represented by composition of two maps $X \rightarrow Z \rightarrow Y$ where either the first is cofibration and the second one is homotopy equivalence or the first one is homotopy equivalence and the latter is a fibration. Is it true that any map can be decomposed as a composition of cofibration and fibration? Can we impose some additional conditions for instance that the cofibration is an $n$-equivalence?

Comment: This is true. A good place to get to grips with it may be Strom's book "Modern Classical Homotopy Thoeory" section 5.8.3, pg. 127.

Comment: We can even say more: Every map $f:X\to Y$ is a composition of a cofibration $i:X\to Z$ and a fibration $p:Z\to Y$  such that either $i$ or $p$ is a homotopy equivalence (we then say that $i$ is an *acyclic cofibration*, or that $p$ is an *acyclic fibration*). You can find a proof for this fact in the answer to my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124930/doubt-about-proof-of-factorization-f-pi-where-i-is-acyclic-cofibration-and. I've worked out all the details in the proof, so you could ask me if something is unclear.